# Android Bump Api Network on main thread exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, android-asynctask

First of all, I'm quite new to the Android and JAVA world (coming from C/C++/Objective-C).
I'm trying to integrate the Android bump API (3.0, latest version) but I'm running into trouble. 
I copied the exemple, it is working fine under Android 2.2, bump services are started correctly, but as for Android 3.0 and upper it does not works.
I've got an exception (the network on main thread one) when loading my activity, I know this exception and how to avoid it, but in this case, Bump state that they run their API in their own thread so I don't really know why I got it. They said that you don't need to run a thread or tasks.

Here is a sample of my Activity

```
public class BumpActivity extends Activity {
private IBumpAPI api;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bump);

    bindService(new Intent(IBumpAPI.class.getName()), connection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CHANNEL_CONFIRMED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.DATA_RECEIVED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.MATCHED);
    filter.addAction(BumpAPIIntents.CONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);



}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {

        Log.i("BumpTest", "onServiceConnected");
        api = IBumpAPI.Stub.asInterface(binder);
        try {
            api.configure("API_KEY", "Bump User");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.w("BumpTest", e);
        }
        Log.d("Bump Test", "Service connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d("Bump Test", "Service disconnected");
    }
};
}
```

Sound like the problem occur during the connection service on the api.configure.... 
Should I run it in a separate thread or in it's own AsynchTask, but then how and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stuck on this problem for a day or so... and literarily 2 minutes after posting it here I resolved it...
I just put the api.configure on a separate thread (shorter than a AsynchTask).

```
private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {

        Log.i("BumpTest", "onServiceConnected");
        api = IBumpAPI.Stub.asInterface(binder);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    api.configure("API_KEY",
                            "Bump User");
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.w("BumpTest", e);
                }

            }
        }.start();

        Log.d("Bump Test", "Service connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.d("Bump Test", "Service disconnected");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make request in background process.

Comment: In fact I already found the answer, I stuck on this problem for a day... and literally 2 minutes after posting it I resolved it... :)

Answer (score 0):

The network on main thread one exception is happening in 2.2 and on 3.0 and above, the difference is that on 3.0 and above they force you to put everything that involves some heavy or slow ops in a different thread, as you said in an asyncTask.

You just have to create an inner [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and on its onBackground method put your api.configure :)

```
class LoadBumpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
        api.configure("9b17d663752843a1bfa4cc72d309339e", "Bump User");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.w("BumpTest", e);
    }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Just call `new LoadBumpAsyncTask().execute()` on your service connected and will work.