# Permission denied in while making http request

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am making request to request with following and i am getting exception in android application.

```
URL url = new URL(strURL);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

try {
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection;
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.connect();

    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        is = httpConn.getInputStream();

    }
} catch (Exception ex) {

    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

getting following exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576339/java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-for-android

Answer (score 2):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` to manifest

Answer (score 2):

First, put this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If your app is going to be released on Android versions higher then 3.0, you must keep in mind that you need to make the http request in an other thread (Option 1 and 2).

Option 1 (not recommended, but it works:
 Add this line:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But I do not reccomend the first option to be honest, but it does work.
 //===========================================================================
 Option 2:

Used this tutorial to make a proper ASyncTask: http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/android/SimpleHttpGetThread.html

//===========================================================================
 Used ASyncTask as final (option 2).

They changed the network permissions  in Android 3.0+

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest.xml

```
<!-- For Getting Network permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```