# Positng XML to HTTP not working

Tags: android, http-post

So im trying to use this api for my heating. In its desciption it says this: "Commands are always sent to the base in form of an XML file. The XML command is sent to the URL: http :///data/changes.xml via http post". This is what im trying to accomplish. My code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String URLchanges;
private String URLstats;
private String myXMLfile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myXMLfile = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <Devices> <Device> <ID>EZR010A49</ID>" +
                    " <DATETIME>2014-01-20T11:40:00</DATETIME> </Device> </Devices>";
    URLchanges = "http://192.168.178.37/data/changes.xml";
    URLstats = "http://192.168.178.37/data/static.xml";
    postXML();
}

private void postXML() {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(URLchanges);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        output.write(myXMLfile.getBytes());
        output.flush();
        Log.d("posted", "posted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("ERROR", "error: see log");
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

However I get this Exception in my Log:

```
01-17 15:19:48.407 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-17 15:19:48.434 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
01-17 15:19:48.434 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
01-17 15:19:48.435 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
01-17 15:19:48.435 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
01-17 15:19:48.435 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
01-17 15:19:48.436 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
01-17 15:19:48.437 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
01-17 15:19:48.437 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
01-17 15:19:48.437 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
01-17 15:19:48.438 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
01-17 15:19:48.438 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
01-17 15:19:48.439 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
01-17 15:19:48.440 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
01-17 15:19:48.441 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
01-17 15:19:48.441 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
01-17 15:19:48.442 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
01-17 15:19:48.443 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.example.ester.heizungapp.MainActivity.postXML(MainActivity.java:64)
01-17 15:19:48.443 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.example.ester.heizungapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
01-17 15:19:48.444 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
01-17 15:19:48.444 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
01-17 15:19:48.447 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
01-17 15:19:48.447 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
01-17 15:19:48.447 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
01-17 15:19:48.448 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
01-17 15:19:48.448 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 15:19:48.450 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-17 15:19:48.451 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
01-17 15:19:48.452 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-17 15:19:48.452 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
01-17 15:19:48.453 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
01-17 15:19:48.453 7484-7484/com.example.ester.heizungapp D/ERROR: error: see log
```

The XML code is copied directly from the api description. Which can be downloaded [here](https://www.moehlenhoff.de/images/content/oem/Alpha2_XML_Schnittstellen_Informationen.zip) if anyone is interested.

If anyone has an Idea what could be wrong, I would really appreciate your advice!

Comment: internet permissions in manifest?

Comment: 1) You are missing internet permission in manifest, 2) You cannot perform network operation on main thread.

Comment: Try to add Internet permission to your manifest. Please see this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576339/java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-for-android)

Comment: Try to add Internet permission to your manifest. See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576339/java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-for-android

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot to add the internet permission in this project. However this was not the original problem. I still get an Exception after that. I edited the main post with the proper error. Do you know what is worng? Thanks for your answers btw!

Comment: Do a web search for `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.  You'll get lots of answers.  Generally when you get an exception you don't understand, that is the first thing you should do.