# Android java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets

I'm an android beginner.
I want to create a ServerSocket, but it always calls "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied" back on line "serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);"
I want to know why, thank you.

ServerThread.java

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    ServerSocket serverSocket ;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("IN");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // null
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ServerThread().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.net.SocketException: Permission denied for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576339/java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-for-android)

Comment: I saw that before but I have already added the permission. And he didn't use socket, so I ask here, thank you.

Comment: no problem, i thought it was a duplicate because I didn't see your manifest

Comment: check if the port is not blocked by the firewall